# How to test if Callable parameter will return a string with Reflection?

Tags: php, reflection, callback, php-7, callable

I have a function which expects a `Callable` parameter. I want to determine that this callable returns a string and if it doesn't an exception should be thrown.

I tried searching for this, but no luck. Does the PHP reflection API provide functionality like this? I don't want to run the method and see if it actually returns a string.

Example of what I need:

```
class MyClass
{
    protected static $overrider = null;

    public static function setOverrider(Callable $callback)
    {
        // Pseudo code start
        if (!$callback returns string) {
            throw new \Exception('Wasnt a string!');
        }
        // Pseudo code end     

        self::$overrider = $callback;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that you are working with PHP 7+, right?
Because PHP < 7 doesn't support return type declarations.

Check this:
https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types (proposal)
http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations

Comment: Yes I am, but I'm not sure how that's relevant. I added an example of what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    protected static $overrider = null;

    public static function setOverrider(Callable $callback)
    {
        $reflection = new ReflectionFunction($callback);
        if ('string' != $reflection->getReturnType()) {
            throw new \Exception('Wasnt a string!');
        }  

        self::$overrider = $callback;
    }
}
```

So, as I mentioned previously in comments: You need to declare returning type of your callable (which is a [PHP7+ feature](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations)). It is a MUST, otherwise, it will not work

Like this:

```
function my_function(): string
{
    return 'hello';
}
```

or like this if you prefer anonymous functions ([Closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php)):

```
$my_callable = function(): string {
    return 'hello';
}
```

It is as simple as this:
The interpreter cannot know the returning data type of a function without invoking it if you don't first tell the interpreter what should return the function in question.

Comment: Nevermind, I apologize. This is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not going to enforce strict types in my project. I assumed that I will be able to fetch the return type without invoking the callable.

Comment: I really think that my answer absolutely fits with your question.
Do you want to know the returning type of your 'callable' without invoking, right?

Comment: Yep, it fits, hence the accept. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is as simple as this:
The interpreter cannot know the returning data type of a function without invoking it if you don't first tell the interpreter what should return the function in question.